# Git unable to resolve references when pushing

Tags: git, github

I am having an issue with Git.  For unknown reasons, my master branch has somehow gotten corrupted. I have a local commit that I want to push up, but when I push, I get this:

```
git push origin master
error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/master: No such file or directory
error: cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

I have seen the issue on other boards, but usually referring to pulls and not pushes. Nevertheless, I have tried their solutions, but to no avail:

1. Tried amending to my current commit and pushing
2. cleaned my git repository with `git gc --prune=now`
3. Tried `rm .git/refs/removes/origin/master`

None have solved my issues.  Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: What's `git for-each-ref '**/master'` say? To be specific, I suspect you've got a `refs/heads/refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: It says `fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000 for refs/remotes/origin/master`

Comment: What's that `git for-each-ref` say?

Comment: *my apologies.*  You've somehow gotten an all-zeroes sha in that ref, and it just didn't occur to me that f-e-r would punt like that.  `git update-ref -d refs/remotes/origin/master; git fetch origin`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not seem to work: the first part of the command (the update-ref) throws an error: `error: unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/master: No such file or directory
`.  On an interesting note, just running `git for-each-ref` shows `fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000 for refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  Did I... did I lose my head?

Comment: It's time to get brutal.  These are remote refs, they'll be refreshed when you fetch.  `rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin`.

Comment: btw don't worry, the net effect of `update-ref -d`'ing every `origin` ref  in that directory is _exactly_ this. the update-ref does additionally guard against simultaneous updates, but I trust  there's no one else operating on this repo?

Comment: Correct, just me. I shall attempt!

Comment: It worked! Would you mind forming these comments into an answer below? :)

Comment: For future readers - if you have "sudo" permissions, that may solve your problem (e.g. "sudo git push...")

Answer (score 46, accepted):

(a worthwhile tl;dr from @NeTeInStEiN:

The nuclear option is `rm -rf .git/refs/remotes/origin`, and that's what it took here)

**edit:** I've run across part of this behavior in one of my own repos, I can get git to reproduce the f-e-r failure without the `rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master` hack:

- clone a repo
- delete the origin's primary branch (the one its `HEAD`'s attached to)
- run `git fetch --prune` in the clone

The fetch will produce a dangling-ref warning, and `git for-each-ref` will fail with a familiar message:

```
~/sandbox/20/buddy$ git fetch --prune
From /home/jthill/sandbox/20/source/.
 x [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/master
   (refs/remotes/origin/HEAD has become dangling)
~/sandbox/20/buddy$ git f-e-r
fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

but that doesn't break the push, I've tried with every setting of `push.default`, nor does it break `git update-ref -d`.

However, googling the push message did get me this:

> [I had just rebooted from a BSOD the other day [...] then git push.  And that’s when I got a complaint about “Unable to resolve reference refs/remotes/origin/master…”. [...]  So, I opened up the master file and it was full of spaces!  Well, that’s no good.  In order to fix it, I did this: [your `rm`, and then `git fetch`]](http://blog.peterritchie.com/?p=1441)

---

See comments above for the blow-by-blow, tl;dr is, because these were remote refs, which `git fetch` completely refreshes, and because the damage was such that [`for-each-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) and [`git update-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-ref.html) failed to work at all, the nuclear option `rm -rf refs/remotes/origin; git fetch` was guaranteed to restore the remote properly.

In other circumstances,  if there'd been no easy way to restore the damaged refs or for  curiosity, `find .git/refs/remotes/origin -type f` to check for locks or using reflogs (those files are in `.git/logs`) to recover content would have helped but it wasn't necessary here.  I think I missed a bet by not doing the `find` first, `*.lock` files from a `kill -9`ed earlier command look likely here, but I suspected an ambiguous ref and f-e-r is my first step for those.

---

Comment: For me an additional `rm .git/packed-refs` was needed to resolve this error.

Comment: as always the nuclear option is the best, worked for me! :)

Answer (score 7):

Remove the following directory from .git folder -> .git/refs/remotes/origin

This will remove all the remote branches and you need to fetch them again using -> git fetch.
This should fix the issue.

Comment: This is very dangerous operation. Editting of git directory is not recomended.

Comment: @Arci yeah but that was the only that woked anyway

Answer (score 4):

1. just go to this dir. in your project and delete the origin folder from your project:

---

```
.git/refs/remotes/origin
```

2. now just run this commannd:

---

```
git fetch --prune
```

or you may fetch all your branches by using this  `git fetch --all`.

now `push` or `pull` your code with,
this works for me,

Answer (score 2):

Note: with Git 2.5 (July 2015), [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) will be a bit more precise when it fails on a "missing object".

See [commit 501cf47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501cf47cddfbf8040b6f9b8ac06d13094a70f729), [commit f551707](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5517074f8f5cecc773b2ff927be4a059f2c9db0) (03 Jun 2015), and [commit 8afc493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8afc493d115e35092be8de3a441317f175928ab5), [commit c3e23dc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3e23dc117beae7e89e81aed28b0e082a14d672e) (02 Jun 2015) by [Michael Haggerty (`mhagger`)](https://github.com/mhagger).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9d71c5f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d71c5f408dabb94f21891f69de17aa72d4787c3), 24 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `for-each-ref`: report broken references correctly
>
> If there is a loose reference file with invalid contents, "`git for-each-ref`" incorrectly reports the problem as being a missing
>   object with name NULL_SHA1:

```
$ echo '12345678' >.git/refs/heads/nonsense
$ git for-each-ref
fatal: missing object 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 for refs/heads/nonsense
```

> With an explicit "`--format`" string, it can even report that the
>   reference validly points at NULL_SHA1:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(objectname) %(refname)'
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 refs/heads/nonsense
$ echo $?
0
```

> `NULL_SHA1` is used to indicate an "`invalid object name`" throughout our
>   code (and the code of other git implementations), so it is vastly more
>   likely that an on-disk reference was set to this value due to a
>   software bug than that `NULL_SHA1` is the legitimate SHA-1 of an actual
>   object.
>   **Therefore, if a loose reference has the value `NULL_SHA1`,
>   consider it to be broken.**

Answer (score 1):

rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/master

run git fetch --prune

Answer (score 0):

I am probably a day late and a dollar short, but I recently experienced the same error message while setting up my first repository for school. I have looked at the answers above and none of them solved my problem. What did solve my problem was : `sudo git push` and entered admin password...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to solve this is to first check if the git repository you are pushing your commits is getting updated with your commits or not. If yes then you can delete the cloned repository on your local machine and then again clone it.
This way the error will go away.
Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: I'm the only developer using the repo.  I cannot comment on
>   the impact of this hack on repo's with more users/complexity. Please back everything up first.

After trying everything in this thread an others I ended up deleting the branch file from the remote server file system located at \refs\heads\.  I tried deleting it from the local computer first as Prateek suggested but that had no effect.

Ex. 
Lets say my Repo is named "Foo" and my branch is named "Bar".
on System hosting the GIT repo open the repo directory (Foo) and navigate to the file
"Foo\refs\heads\" Then rename (eventually delete) the branch file named Bar.

Git will recreate the branch file during the push operation.

After the push, I switched to master and merged the "Bar" branch without issue

Answer (score 0):

In the base directory of your local repo you will find .git/refs/remotes/origin. In this directory, your branch's namesake file should contain the commit ID (40 alphanumeric characters) of the latest commit of that branch. If that is not the case, get the last commit ID of your branch and update the contents of the file. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Raw, but the only solution that worked to me:

- rename 'origin' remote with 'another name' and use that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).