# Clone repo, create branch, add something, send it

Tags: git

after a lot of posts I am close to resignation (can't sleep because of that for now). I have a repo, I just need to clone it, create a branch, do something there and make it public to the rest.
So first I am cloning

```
git clone my_repo_online
```

next I create my branch

```
git checkout -b feature/featureX
```

make some changes, commit them and want to push it to server. I've got error about upstream so I set it to:

```
git push -u origin feature/featureX
```

And I've got counting objects, writing info etc, and then

```
remote: error: Cannot update the ref 'refs/heads/...'
```

I've done something like this hundreds times, but this time I think I forgot something. 
This is my first day in new company and I lost a "first day commit" chance, and I am not sure if I don't understand it, I messed everything or maybe I don't have some access rights

BTW: when creating branch like 'new' it works perfectly, but 'feature/new' don't. And there is no feature directory/branch on remote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git unable to resolve references when pushing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749886/git-unable-to-resolve-references-when-pushing)

Comment: Is there by any chance a branch called `feature` on the remote?

Comment: @1615903 I checked this, on remote there is only master and develop