# Github desktop "error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unable to resolve reference' (

Tags: git, github

[image]

I suddenly, after committing my changed files, could not click on 'push', instead it said: "publish branch" (see image). So when I tried push that button ("publish branch"), I got the error as seen in the image.

I have not done anything unusual, other than just committing changed files and pushing them. What is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git unable to resolve references when pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749886/git-unable-to-resolve-references-when-pushing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+cannot+lock+ref+unable+to+resolve+reference